# Run shell script failed when I use Xcode to build project with release deployment.

Tags: ios, node.js, xcode, shell

#### Issue Description

The log of error when build project looks like below.

- node /Users/niyao/Company/Projects/EVE/EVERN/node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js bundle --entry-file index.ios.js --platform ios --dev false --reset-cache --bundle-output /Users/niyao/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/EVE-bzggtbnrxixkvwgqyewmpxepvljo/Build/Products/Release-iphonesimulator/EVE.app/main.jsbundle --assets-dest /Users/niyao/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/EVE-bzggtbnrxixkvwgqyewmpxepvljo/Build/Products/Release-iphonesimulator/EVE.app

fs.js:584
  return binding.open(pathModule._makeLong(path), stringToFlags(flags), mode);

Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'package.json'

#### Error Scenario

After I use package.json as below to npm instal new version, the error happens within release deployment scheme.

```js
{
  "name": "NYProject",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start",
    "lint": "./node_modules/eslint/bin/eslint.js index.ios.js index.android.js react/",
    "watch": "npm-watch"
  },
  "watch": {
    "lint": {
      "patterns": [
        "react",
        "index.ios.js",
        "index.android.js"
      ],
      "extensions": "js",
      "ignore": ".node_modules",
      "quiet": false
    }
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "15.3.1",
    "react-native": "^0.32.0",
    "react-redux": "^4.4.5",
    "redux": "^3.5.2",
    "redux-logger": "^2.6.1",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.1.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-eslint": "^6.1.2",
    "eslint": "^3.3.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^6.1.2",
    "eslint-plugin-react-native": "^2.0.0",
    "npm-watch": "^0.1.6"
  }
}
```

The shell runs failed when build project within ***Release*** build configuration.

"./NYProject/node_modules/react-native/packager/react-native-xcode.sh"

Expected Results

Xcode could run shell when build the project. Before I upgrade the package.json configuration, it did run successfully.

#### Additional Information

- React Native version: 
  react-native-cli: 0.2.0
  react-native: 0.32.0
- Platform(s) (iOS, Android, or both?): 
  Xcode 7.3.1 iOS
- Operating System (macOS, Linux, or Windows?): 
  OS X 10.11

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, and for me, simply upgrading to react-native 0.33.0 solved the problem.

Comment: Yeah, I finally solve this problem by upgrading react-native and react version.And I find out that react-native version must match the react version. Thank you for answer. : )